# C# Nullable<DateTime> to string

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a `DateTime?` variable, sometimes the value is `null`, how can I return an empty string `""` when the value is `null` or the `DateTime` value when not `null`?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
string date = myVariable.HasValue ? myVariable.Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
```

Comment: What!? You can just call .ToString() on the Nullable<DateTime> instance to get String.Empty. Even Eric Lippert (who might have even implemented this behavior) notes this. _That_ should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @codekaizen - I get an exception when I try that.  So no, that would not be the accepted answer.  Perhaps this is not a problem in more recent versions of c# or .net?

Comment: @k.robinson - perhaps that is because you are using a boxed reference to the instance. Please realize that I'm advocating the same as Eric Lippert - one of the creators of the .Net platform itself - is pointing out in his answer. If you have a problem, you might want to reconsider if "select isn't broken" (http://www.pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips).

Comment: @codekaizen - Ok.  I still wish I could do this without a typecast:  dateTimeField.Text = dateTimeObj.HasValue ? ((DateTime) dateTimeObj).ToShortDateString() : string.Empty;

Answer (score 112):

Though many of these answers are correct, all of them are needlessly complex. **The result of calling ToString on a nullable DateTime is already an empty string if the value is logically null.** Just call ToString on your value; it will do exactly what you want.

Comment: Unless you want to use the DateTime properties like `.Day` `.Week` because that will give you the entire DateTime string and lose the power of the DateTime class. e.g. `myVariable.Value.Hour.ToString()`. Just an example reason why you might want to do otherwise.

Comment: @baron, those properties aren't `Nullable`.

Answer (score 18):

Actually, this is the default behaviour for Nullable types, that without a value they return nothing:

```
public class Test {
    public static void Main() {
        System.DateTime? dt = null;
        System.Console.WriteLine("<{0}>", dt.ToString());
        dt = System.DateTime.Now;
        System.Console.WriteLine("<{0}>", dt.ToString());
    }
}
```

this yields

```
<>
<2009-09-18 19:16:09>
```

Comment: +1 Did not know this. However, you cannot supply a formatting string this way.

Comment: Hm, right. Though this may not be a problem in this case. I didn't know this myself too until yesterday, though. Stumbled over it when looking at `Nullable<T>` in Reflector :-)

Answer (score 8):

Calling `.ToString()` on a `Nullable<T>` that is `null` will return an empty string.

Answer (score 7):

You could write an extension method

```
public static string ToStringSafe(this DateTime? t) {
  return t.HasValue ? t.Value.ToString() : String.Empty;
}

...
var str = myVariable.ToStringSafe();
```

Comment: Or better yet: make it generic: `public static string ToSafeString<T>(this T? obj) where T : struct` :)

Comment: Holy smokes, didn't realize .NET had this ability!

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is to just simply call `.ToString()`. It handles `Nullable<T>` object for `null` value.

Here is the [source of .NET Framework](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs,d83d2db767b43db7,references) for `Nullable<T>.ToString()`:

```
public override string ToString() {
    return hasValue ? value.ToString() : "";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime? d;
// stuff manipulating d;
return d != null ? d.Value.ToString() : String.Empty;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime? MyNullableDT;
....
if (MyNullableDT.HasValue)
{
    return MyNullableDT.Value.ToString();
}
return "";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (aDate.HasValue)
    return aDate;
else
    return string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime d?;
string s = d.HasValue ? d.ToString() : string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.tostring?view=netframework-4.8):

> The text representation of the value of the current Nullable object if the HasValue property is true, or an empty string ("") if the HasValue property is false.

Comment: This was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1446033/10927863) by [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert)

Answer (score 0):

As Eric Lippert's answer. I think this will This code should meet the requirements.

```
Nullable<DateTime> nullableDatetime = null;
string? datetimeString = nullableDatetime.ToString();
string nullableString = datetimeString ?? string.Empty;
```