# Nullable ToString()

Tags: c#, nullable

I see everywhere constructions like:

```
int? myVar = null;
string test = myVar.HasValue ? myVar.Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
```

Why not use simply:

```
string test = myVar.ToString();
```

Isn't that exactly the same ?
At least Reflector says that:

```
public override string ToString()
{
  if (!this.HasValue)
  {
    return "";
  }
  return this.value.ToString();
}
```

So, is that correct (the shorter version) or am I missing something?

Comment: I haven't seen code like this :)

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You are quite correct. Also in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445766/c-nullabledatetime-to-string), the former solution is suggested while nobody actually notices `ToString()` already gives the correct answer.

Maybe the argument for the more verbose solution is readability: When you call `ToString()` on something that is *supposed* to be `null`, you usually *expect* a `NullReferenceException`, although here it isn't thrown.

Comment: Actually, at least two people noticed: Eric Lippert and Johannes Rössel.

Comment: While I'm sure that isn't what you meant, the reference isn't actually null here. Nullable<T> is a value type. This is why calling `ToString()` works without any `NullReferenceException` being thrown.

Comment: If that was the mentality, you'd expect `.HasValue` to still throw that exception.

Comment: Another reason people use the verbose version could be for parity with expressions like `myNullableDateTime.HasValue ? myNullableDateTime.Value.ToString("d") : null` where you do need the unwrapped object to access the desired `ToString` method. Of course, there's a more concise solution for that too: `$"{myNullableDateTime:d}"`

Answer (score 14):

I think that many people have such checks because it is not a natural behavior of an object that can hold null value.

Comment: @Andrew, agreed, because people (like me) think at first that it will throw an exception.

Comment: I had no idea this was the behavior.  I definitely would have thought that any construct which returns true for (x == null) would also throw a NullReferenceException if you call x.ToString().

Answer (score 5):

No, you're correct, the shorter version is the same as what other folks have done in that regard.  The other construct I tend to use a lot instead of the ternary with nullables is the null coalescing operator,. which also protects you from nulls.  For ToString() it's not necessary (as you pointed out) but for default int values (for example) it works nicely, e.g.:

```
int page = currentPage ?? 1;
```

that lets you do all the integer operations on page w/o first explicitly null checking and calling for the value in currentPage (where currentPage is an int? perhaps passed as a param)

Answer (score 5):

I know, long after it was relevant, but ... I suspect it is because for nullable types like int? the .ToString() method does not allow you to use format strings. See [How can I format a nullable DateTime with ToString()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833054/how-can-i-format-a-nullable-datetime-with-tostring) . Perhaps in the original code, there was a format string in .ToString(), or perhaps the coder forgot that .ToString() without the format string was still available on nullable types.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it is just to follow a pattern? Or they don't know the backend. You are right that the code is exactly the same. You can even do:

```
int? i = null;
i.ToString(); //No NullReferenceException
```

Comment: You might need to take the long route if ToString() needs to be of invariant culture, as nullables do not have it in their menu.

Answer (score 3):

`int?` is syntax sugar which simplifies declaration of nullable variable. 
It is the same as `Nullable<int>`.

So if you take a look at the implementation of `ToString()` method for `Nullable<T>` *(see below)*, you can notice, that it returns empty string in case if it has no value.

```
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
      if (!this.hasValue)
        return "";
      return this.value.ToString();
    }
}
```

What MSDN says:

> Nullable.ToString Method
>
> Returns the text representation of the value of the current Nullable object
>   if the HasValue property is true, or an empty string ("") if the
>   HasValue property is false.

So the following code will print empty string to console instead of throwing `ArgumentNullException` exception.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int? a = null;
    Console.WriteLine(a.ToString()); // Prints empty string to console.
}
```