# How can I cast a System.Guid to a string in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following field definition in a class:

```
   public Nullable<System.Guid> GlobalId { get; set; }
```

I have another class with the following:

```
   public string GlobalId { get; set; }
```

I would like to put the value of from the field with type System.Guid into the string.

I tried to do this here:

```
        var questionIds = _questionsRepository.GetAll()
            .Where(m => m.Problem != null &&
            m.Problem.SubTopic != null &&
            m.Problem.SubTopic.Topic != null &&
            m.Problem.SubTopic.Topic.SubjectId == 1)
            .Select(m => new QuestionHeader { GlobalId = (string) m.GlobalId })
            .ToList();
        return questionIds;
```

But it's giving me an error saying:

```
   Cannot convert type 'System.Guid?' to 'string'
```

Can someone tell me how I could do this?

Comment: Please look at the docs for [Nullable(T).ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hd15ket(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I'd recommend you to read some basic c# tutorials. you'll enjoy understand the reasoning behind a lot of "weird errors"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get the string representation of the GUID by calling `ToString()` on it.

As your GUID is nullable, check if it's null before calling `ToString()`:

```
string myString = guid.HasValue ? guid.Value.ToString() : "default string value";
```

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449008/nullable-tostring, there is no need if you want to represent no-value as empty string.

Comment: Well, this answer is still a good way to do it if one wants to have a default value.

Comment: @Euphoric @Euphoric True, but as you said it implies you get `string.Empty` in case it's null (and I don't know what the OP wants as a default value).

Answer (score 3):

You don't cast to string. You use `ToString()` method.

Like this:

```
GlobalId = m.GlobalId.ToString()
```

Comment: The Guid is nullable, you should check if it is null.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `ToString()` method

```
Guid? g = null;    
string s = g.ToString();
```

in case of `null` it will return `String.Empty` otherwise you'll get string representation of your `Guid`

Answer (score 3):

You can convert a Guid with .ToString():

```
Guid gid = Guid.NewGuid();

string myID = gid.ToString();
```

Or using

**`Convert.ToString`**

Like:

```
Guid gid = Guid.NewGuid();

string myID = Convert.ToString(gid);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Convert.ToString` instead of `(string)`

```
GlobalId =  Convert.ToString(m.GlobalId)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
GlobalId = m.GlobalId.ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```