# Datetime? to string

Tags: c#

I need to convert a `Datetime?` to a string. The `??` operator dosent work and calling `tostring` on a `null` would make things fall over. Any advice on how to handle `datetime?` Thanks

Below is my code for context. `o.CustomerRequiredDate` is a `Datetime?` and `PredictedActivationDate` is a `string`. Both need to stay as the datatype they currently are.

```
 {
       rsp = (from r in db.btRequests
                                      join o in db.NewOrders
                                      on r.ID equals o.RequestId
                                      join s in db.Status
                                      on r.Status equals s.ID.ToString()
                                      select new DataLayer.OrderResponse
                                      {
                                          RequestID = requestID,
                                          Message = s.StatusDescription,
                                          OrderStatus = r.Status.ToString(),
                                          PredictedActivationDate =r.Status == "3" || r.Status == "4" || r.Status == "5"
                                          || r.Status == "6" || r.Status == "9" ? (o.CustomerRequiredDate ?? ""): ""

                                      }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445766/c-nullabledatetime-to-string

Comment: General observation, btRequests' `Status` field is holding a `string` yet stores `"3"`, `"4"` - should probably be an `int` field.

Comment: @Kieren Johnstone This is a generic webservice across a few diffrent ordering platforms. Status isnt always an int

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do

```
o.CustomerRequiredDate.HasValue ? o.CustomerRequiredDate.Value.ToString() : ""
```

Comment: +1 The trick is in using the `Value` property instead of just the object on its own.

Comment: On the left of ':' you have a DateTime and a string on the right of ':' It doesn't work!

Comment: The result of `Nullable<T>.ToString` is already an empty string if the value is null, you can simply write `o.CustomerRequiredDate.ToString()`

Comment: I think the .Value approach is valid, especially if he eventually wants to use the other .ToString overloads related to DateTime class.

Comment: Wow, thatnks for all your quick replys

Answer (score 6):

```
o.CustomerRequiredDate.ToString()
```

It returns an empty string for a DateTime? with a null value and the DateTime.ToString otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming `o.CustomerRequiredDate` is your `DateTime?`.

Try

```
o.CustomerRequiredDate.HasValue ? o.CustomerRequiredDate.ToString() : string.Empty
```

instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
o.CustomerRequiredDate.HasValue ? o.CustomerRequiredDate.Value.ToString() : string.Empty
```

Answer (score 2):

Outside of SQL for moment, [`Nullable<T>.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hd15ket.aspx) is documented to return an empty string if `HasValue` is false (ie., it "is null").

If you are concerned that the statements

```
DateTime? date = null;
string output = date.ToString();
```

will "fall over," fear not. Of course, if using the expression in Linq, it would be up to the provider (-to-SQL, -to-EF), to behave properly.

Answer (score 1):

A nullable value is never null in the sense that you can't use `ToString` on it:

```
o.CustomerRequiredDate.ToString()
```

However, you might want a different result than the default empty string for a null value:

```
o.CustomerRequiredDate.HasValue ? o.CustomerRequiredDate.Value.ToString() : "No date"
```