# nullable int (Int?) not throwing null reference exception

Tags: c#

I have encountered the code something like this

```
int? x = new int();
x = null;
var y = x.toString();
```

My understanding is that it should throw a null reference exception. But the code is not breaking and I am getting the value of y as "". Please let me understand that what's happening here in behind.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449008/nullable-tostring, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445766/c-sharp-nullabledatetime-to-string

Comment: In short, because `int? x = null` creates a new `Nullable<int>` which is _not_ null. See also https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/nullable.cs#L74. Though the links above don't really explain that.

Comment: @CodeCaster yes actually the above links asserts my statement but don't explain that why and how it happens.

Comment: I am looking for better explanation that why it happens.

Comment: @VIVEK See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446838/why-does-tostring-on-a-null-string-cause-a-null-error-when-tostring-works for explanation

Comment: @Magnus thanx. It explains me well.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is not null.
You are setting null the value of `Nullable<int>`, which is designed to return an empty string if the value is null.